# Sharing photos with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, share, photo, uiactivityviewcontroller

how to share a grid of images (photos) in an application for iOS?
I know i must use UIActivityViewController, but i don't find the right way to write the code , il want to use a swipe gesture to push my grid and open a window with the applications print, copy, facebook, messenger etc... or any applications of sharing in my simulator

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not correct to use swipe gesture on grid, that is basically `UICollectionView`. Usually, app provide long tap gesture to enter in multi-selection mode and after that provide access to sharing.
You can use [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data) to get familiar with data sharing.
Also keep in mind, that when you use simulator to test your app you would have a few sharing options, because simulator does not have a lot apps that support sharing. It is much more convenient to use device instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i’ll try to convert my grid into an image.